# Automatically add a voucher code if the URL conains a KeyWord in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

The main goal that I want to achieve is to add a voucher code if the user has clicked on a specific external link that point to my shop.
So the (javascript?) script will analyze the url and if it contains any selected keyword will add the voucher.

Anyone knows how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty simple solution.
I made a module.

You can find it here: [GITHUB](https://github.com/univers3/addVoucherByLink)

Was pretty easy:

- Generated a basic module [HERE](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator)
- Selected **Header Hook** for my new module
- Modified the **header hook function** in the **modulename.php** file in root with this one:

> ```
> public function hookHeader()
> {
>     $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
>     $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
>     if (Tools::getValue('voucher')){
>         $cartVoucher = Tools::getValue('voucher');
>         $idDiscount = Discount::getIdByName($cartVoucher);
>         Context::getContext()->cart->addDiscount($idDiscount);
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope will help someone.
Thanks to all.