# Add voucher by link - 1.7.8.6

Tags: php, prestashop

I've tried another solution provided on StackOverflow some years ago, with a custom module:

```
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
        if (Tools::getValue('voucher')){
            $cartVoucher = Tools::getValue('voucher');
            $idDiscount = CartRule::getIdByCode($cartVoucher);
            Context::getContext()->cart->addCartRule($idDiscount);
        }
    }
```

The behavior expected is by going to [www.mywebsite.com/cart?id_product=16&add=1&voucher=TEST_VOUCHER](http://www.mywebsite.com/cart?id_product=16&add=1&voucher=TEST_VOUCHER)  the product and voucher should be added to the cart.

Problem is that everything is working as expected on my local machine ( version 1.7.6.1 ) and is not when I'm trying in prod ( 1.7.8.6 ). Online the product is added to the cart, but the voucher is not.

Not sure what might be the problem :/

Edit: As a reference, this is the old topic: [Automatically add a voucher code if the URL conains a KeyWord in Prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194474/automatically-add-a-voucher-code-if-the-url-conains-a-keyword-in-prestashop)

Edit: I tried to create a cart, without success. This code 'works' as the previous one, just by doing this on whatever link [www.mywebsite.com/?voucher=TEST_VOUCHER](http://www.mywebsite.com/?voucher=TEST_VOUCHER) and adding the product to the card afterward.

but that's not what I need, unfortunately.

```
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');

        if (Tools::getValue('voucher')){

            $cartVoucher = Tools::getValue('voucher');        
            $idDiscount = CartRule::getIdByCode($cartVoucher);

        if (!$this->context->cart->id) {
                if (Context::getContext()->cookie->id_guest) {
                    $guest = new Guest(Context::getContext()->cookie->id_guest);
                    $this->context->cart->mobile_theme = $guest->mobile_theme;
                }
                $this->context->cart->add(); 
                if ($this->context->cart->id) {
                    $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
                }
            }

       Context::getContext()->cart->addCartRule($idDiscount);

    }

}
```

Comment: First off check if your production shop has "Re-display cart at login" enabled in "Shop parameters > Customer settings".
And if a customer does not have a cart yet, you should create a new one. (or check if your current context has access to the cart.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not a php developer so I'm just try to wrap my mind around this. I add an edit to my answer, to create a new cart. It's not working still